# Placeholder colours not working CSS

Tags: css, placeholder

I am trying to apply a simple colour to a specific input box. I know that we can do this:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #000000;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
   color: #000000;  
}

:input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #000000;  
}
```

So to get it working on my input box I tried:

```
.search-top-container form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #000000;
}

.search-top-container form input:-moz-placeholder {
   color: #000000;  
}


.search-top-container form input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #000000;  
}
```

But it isn't working. I tried using important tags as well but that doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just to check the obvious: if you do `.search-top-container form input {background:magenta}`, does the text box appear in bright pink?

Comment: Hi, yes I've applied other styling to the input with .search-top-container form input {} I just tried the background and it did display the new colour.

Comment: Okay. Next thing to try: remove `input`. Try just `.search-top-container form :-ms-input-placeholder` (and other prefixes) to see if that works.

Comment: Just tried them without the input but unfortunately no change.

Comment: And lastly, have you tried `:-ms-input-placeholder` alone, without the `.search-top-container form input` part?

Comment: Yes just tried it (and put it on top of my CSS file) but no change.

Comment: Well, if even that doesn't work, I don't know what to suggest. It's not working.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging help, I was worried the syntax I used was incorrect. I'm testing a Wordpress theme so I will ask the developer if there is anything which might be affecting it.

Comment: Can we see your markup of your html starting with `.search-top-container`?

Comment: Which versions of the browsers are you testing?

Answer (score 1):

You're not saying in which browser it isn't working, but you do have an error with the Mozilla code. The latest Mozilla browsers (since v19) work only with two colons, so `::-moz-placeholder` instead of `:-moz-placeholder`.

In addition, the default style for a placeholder contains `opacity:.4`, so if you want cross browser compatibility, you will have to set the opacity too. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-placeholder).

```css
.search-top-container form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #F00000;
  opacity: 1;
}
.search-top-container form input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #F00000;
  opacity: 1;
}
.search-top-container form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #F00000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-top-container">
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Firstname Lastname" />
  </form>
</div>
```

(Note that in this snippet, I used red for the colour, to avoid situations where you might think it's not working because it happens to be the same colour as the default.)